# how to remove horizontal scrollbar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

I create a wordpress theme but i can't delete horizontal scrollbar.
how to delete this scrollbar? plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to **.footer1** in **style.css**:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```